# Rails association help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, hyperlink, devise, associations

Hey I made a scaffold called pictures, but now I need to it to have many tags.
I want it to be so that you can do something like click add tag then fill in a tag, then click add tag ..., this would be in pictures/new and edit, and maybe show.
I don't have a clue how to do this and I am not that great in rails, so be very clear if you can. (maybe there is something in rails like a button that if you click it you execute a function, even then I'm not sure how to go about this)
I am using rails 3.

Comment: If my question is unclear tell me how i can elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you need.:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: thanks, this mostly worked, but their Add fields and Remove fields won't do anything, do you know what is wrong with that

Comment: probably your javascript is not working,could you provide more details,snippets of code would be good and also check the console in your browser to see if your getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin,

I think task number one is to read up on Rails ActiveRecord associations here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Once you have your associations right, I would make tags a sub-resource of pictures in your routes file.  This would allow you to do a POST to :tags with a route like /pictures/{id}/tags

Comment: where do i go to learn how to use post (because I already use associations alot, maybe i could look over the association if i'm missing something) I think that might be what i'm missing