# Rails nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, models, web, nested-attributes

hey I asked a question here [Rails association help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592138/rails-association-help) , this person directed me to learn nested attributes here , http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 , and here http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2 . The link_to 's to add fields wont respond to anything I do

Comment: Usually helpful to post code when you're asking others to debug it. Even better if it's the part containing the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with jimworm in that it would be really helpful to see the relevant parts of the code that you are working with. I also want to point out that from those Railscasts Ryan created the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem which works really well for doing a multi-model form for associated models. I use this gem quite often for my forms.

Comment: I've used that gem and agree it's one that can help.